# iOS distribution methods

Tags: ios, distribution, ios-provisioning, iphone-developer-program

Currently there is a plan in my company to develop an iOS apps (sales tools) for our sales people who are using iPhone, iPad. I understand that we should enroll the "Enterprise Program".

It is also important that our partners, resellers, distributors can use the above mentioned sales tools. Our resellers, partners, and distributors are everywhere globally..(Taiwan, Japan, Europe)

I understand there is a B2B program from Apple that allows you to distribute in-house apps to other companies, enterprises. But currently B2B is only available for US companies/organizations.

Does that means there is no other way for me to distribute apps to other organizations, companies outside US?

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption is partly correct; you can not use the Enterprise Program and the B2B Program is not available outside the US.

You may however distribute your App via iTunes. If you do not want unauthorized people to use it, simply add a login feature. The credentials are given only to your partners and to the iTunes review team.

Comment: By saying 'iTunes' you are referring to the Apple "App Store"?

Comment: Correct, that is what I mean.

Comment: That will subject to Apple's approval? I haven't submit anything like that before (in-house apps for internal usage). What worries me is that Apple might reject the app after months of hard work.

Comment: After reading the guideline, I am not sure by providing customize login feature will violate AppStore submission guidelines? (11. Purchasing and currencies

11.1
Apps that unlock or enable additional features or functionality with mechanisms other than the App Store will be rejected)

Comment: @forestclown if that was the way you interpret it, then how come there is a Facebook app on iTunes?

Comment: Facebook apps are opened for all people, anyone can subscribe. For my apps is only limited to selective people, which is our in-house employees which also extend to partners, and reselles. App Store by default rejects in-house apps as far as I understand.

Comment: @forestclown rest assured that is not the case.

Comment: My concerns are stem from two points: 1) I couldn't locate any in-house apps in AppStore 2) If in-house apps are permitted in AppStore, then what is the purpose of Enterprise Program? I am under the assumptions Apple will reject in-house app submission to AppStore because Enterprise program are meant for that.